# "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'" for python discord bot

Tags: python

I am making a discord bot using python and its saying "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'". I cant figure out why :/

```
def withdraw(person,amount,ininventory,allmoney):
  amount = int(amount)
  if person in allmoney.keys():
    if allmoney[person] > amount:
      if person in ininventory.keys():
        ininventory[person] += amount
        allmoney[person] -= amount
      else:
        ininventory[person] = 0
        ininventory[person] += amount
        allmoney[person] -= amount
      return ininventory[person],allmoney[person],allmoney,ininventory
    else:
      moneynow = allmoney[person]
      allmoney[person] = 0
      return ininventory[person],moneynow,allmoney,ininventory
  else:
    ininventory[person] = 0
    return 0,allmoney[person],allmoney,ininventory
```

"if person in allmoney.keys():" is what its saying "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'" for

and this is whats calling the function.

```
allmoney = {}
ininventory = {}
@client.command()
async def withdraw(ctx, arg):
  global allmoney
  global ininventory
  amountpocket = "broken"
  amountbank = "broken"
  amountpocket,amountbank,allmoney,ininventory = bank.withdraw({ctx.author.name},arg,allmoney,ininventory)
  await ctx.send(f'withdrawed {arg} Dollars!\nYou now have {amountpocket} Dollars in your pocket!\nYou now have {amountbank} in your account!')
```

this is the calling

```
amountpocket,amountbank,allmoney,ininventory = bank.withdraw({ctx.author.name},arg,allmoney,ininventory)
```

I'm sorry if this is not the proper way to ask the questions but i dont know how to use this sight and im new to it.

My last question got shut down i think.

Comment: Why are you passing `ctx.author.name` as a set? `{'string'}` produces an instance of a set in Python and the built-in set data type does not have the required method to test for membership in the object returned by `dict.keys()`. Try just doing `bank.withdraw(ctx.author.name, ...)` instead, removing the curly braces.

Comment: oh ok i will do that

Comment: it still does not work...

Comment: Even if it still doesn't work, it's still less wrong than the original, which could _never_ work. Don't turn down a change that fixes _something_ just because it doesn't fix _everything_.

Comment: I fixed the issue but i dont know how to close the thread so if a moderator can for me please do

Answer (score 0):

Verify the data type of `allmoney`. Unhashable type set means that you are treating a set as if it was a dictionary. Sets do not have keys thus calling `allmoney.keys()` will give an error. Sets are like arrays which only contain values.

`example_set = {"apple", "orange", "pineapple"}`

`example_dict = {"fruit": "apple", "vegetable": "lettuce"}`